# Increase Range of Y Axis Google Charts

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have the following URL to generate a line chart, however I'm struggling to get the Y Axis to cooperate with the range.

I was under the impression that adding the `chxr` parameter would fix this?

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=lc&chs=500x250&chco=FF0000,00FFFF,00FF00&chxr=0,10,200&chxt=x,y&chxl=0:|01/01/2017|02/01/2017|03/01/2017&chdl=first+legend%7Csecond+legend%7Cthird+legend&chtt=My+Google+Chart&chts=000000,24&chd=t:5,10,50|50,65,120|26,65,42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chxr` *is used* to set the axis range

as noted in the docs, the parameter uses the following syntax...

> `chxr` = `<axis_index>,<start_val>,<end_val>,<opt_step>`

where...

`<axis_index>` = `0` for x-axis

`<axis_index>` = `1` for y-axis

as such, the parameter is defined incorrectly...

where you have --> `chxr=0,10,200`

**change to** --> `chxr=1,10,200`

see following link...

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=lc&chs=500x250&chco=FF0000,00FFFF,00FF00&chxr=1,10,200&chxt=x,y&chxl=0:|01/01/2017|02/01/2017|03/01/2017&chdl=first+legend%7Csecond+legend%7Cthird+legend&chtt=My+Google+Chart&chts=000000,24&chd=t:5,10,50|50,65,120|26,65,42

---

note: This API has been deprecated. See the [deprecation policy](https://developers.google.com/chart/terms) for details.

Comment: Thanks for that! If it has been deprecated, is there any other solution you would recommend for generating chart images via API?

Comment: sure, try the newer library found here --> [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/) -- see [Load the Libraries](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs) and here is the reference for [line charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) -- i have several examples, if you need help, just ask! -- will you please mark the answer as accepted? cheers!

Comment: Thanks bro, can these be called from a URL? As with the old API? I can't use javascript as I'm using HTML to PDF library in C# (HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp)

Comment: can't be called from a url necessarily -- but you can create a `.png` image of the chart once it has been generated -- basically, you would have to create a page that generates the chart, then sends the png image back to the server via ajax, then continue with the html to pdf from there -- [this answer and its comments](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38464203/5090771) _somewhat_ describe the process -- _some_ additional info can be found in this [answer / question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38846683/5090771)

Comment: but the deprecation notice was mainly for others that may stumble upon this post, as for the image chart library, google says --> _This gives us the right to turn it off without notice, although we have no plans to do so._