# Google charts how to export multiple charts to png

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I am displaying a Bar chart and a Table chart.
How do I export both the charts together in single png?

Currently I can only print a single chart.

```
function drawBarChart() {

    .......
    var visibleDiv = document.getElementById('visible_div');
    var primaryChart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(visibleDiv);

    var btndownloadchart = document.getElementById('downloadchart');
    btndownloadchart.addEventListener('click', function () {
         this.href=  primaryChart.getImageURI();
        }, false);


    primaryChart.draw(data, primaryOptions);

  }

 function drawTableChart(containerID, dataArray, options) {
    ......

    chart = new google.visualization.Table(containerDiv);
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }

  <a id="downloadchart" class="btn btn-defalt pull-right" href="#"  download="Chart"> Download    </a>
```

Comment: See [How can I get png(base64) with images inside of svg in Google Charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975138/how-can-i-get-pngbase64-with-images-inside-of-svg-in-google-charts)

Comment: See also [Execute Google Chart API (Javascript) in php file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38678239/execute-google-chart-api-javascript-in-php-file)